# Cannot loard secure-storage after updating my app

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've got a random problem with cordova-secure-storage. I'm developping hybrid application. After upgrading my application on my some android phone, i have an error:

`java.lang.Exception: KeyStore doesn't contain alias:...`. I think is a secure-storage error.

I'm using "@awesome-cordova-plugins/secure-storage": "^6.4.0" and "cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo": "^5.1.1"

Anyone have an idea of my problem?